# Is there a way to temporarily turn off exception dialogs in the Delphi 5 IDE without implementing an own exception handler?

Tags: delphi, delphi-5

I've got a very old Delphi 5 project where a bug needs to be fixed.

It loads all right into the Delphi 5 IDE, but on execution I get a lot of Indy Exceptions that *ARE* handled correctly by the program like "connection closed gracefully". These are not a part of the bug I'm trying to fix, but since I get exception dialogs displayed again and again it's an unbelievable pain to debug the app.

Is there a way to temporarily turn off exception dialogs in the Delphi 5 IDE *without implementing an own exception handler*? It would be especially helpful when only some specific exception dialogs like "connection closed gracefully" are not displayed.

Comment: Are you talking about exceptions in the Delphi DEBUGGER or during IDE startup? It sounds like you simply need to open the Debugger Options and ignore the exceptions you don't want to break on.

Comment: thanks @WarrenP, I've incorrectly assumed that the language exception tab has been implemented only from delphi 6 on; now, if you change your comment to an answer... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the debugger settings there is an option 'break on language exceptions'. **Turn it OFF (uncheck).** You can do this anytime, even in the middle of a debugging session.

If that option is switched on, the debugger will break immediately when exceptions are raised, even if the code subsequently handles them. This is sometimes important in debugging. But it can also be annoying if you're not interested in seeing all those exceptions, such as in your case.

You can also leave 'break on language exceptions' checked, but add the exception types that you don't want to break on, to the list of excluded exception types there in that dialog. I rarely use that option but sometimes it can also be helpful.

Comment: Other options include 1) wrapping the offending code in breakpoints that dynamically disable/reenable the debugger from handling exceptions, and 2) adding `EIdException` to the debugger's list of exceptions to ignore.

Comment: Never knew about option 1 until you mentioned it and I clicked on the advanced dialog for breakpoint properties! But I THINK I included your option 2 in my answer.

Comment: yes, you did, but I expanded on it by specifying *WHICH* exception type to ignore.

Comment: Understood - I assume EIdException is the Indy exception type. Tnx

Comment: Yes, `EIdException` is the base type for all Indy-based exceptions (there are many derivatives).